# How to rotate TIFF image with LibTiff

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, libtiff

I tried to rotate a single page TIFF image following to this guide.
https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/39c566d1-98fa-4b46-aa7a-e03ee2eada8c.htm

and I need to maintain all TIFF TAG data.

So I can't rotate it.

Any suggestion?

Edited for more information :

I modified code aim to maintain same TAG (TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, TiffTag.COMPRESSION)

```
int width = input.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
int height = input.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();
int samplesPerPixel = input.GetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL)[0].ToInt();
int bitsPerSample = input.GetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE)[0].ToInt();
int photo = input.GetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC)[0].ToInt();
int compression = = input.GetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION)[0].ToInt();// I added this row
....
output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, width);
output.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, height);
output.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, samplesPerPixel);//Sample use 3
output.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, bitsPerSample);//Sample use 8
output.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, height);
output.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, (Photometric)photo);// I changed this
output.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG);
output.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, (Compression));// I changed this
```

and I got this output 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHSr5.png

Comment: Whats wrong with your try?

Comment: I got black output @Reniuz

Comment: And without your tags works well?

Comment: No, It did not work well @Reniuz